# Is it possible to pass data to html form through a link to html file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Here is an html form page

https://www.amazon.in/gp/help/customer/ces/phone-popup.html

which has input fields phone number and time to call.

Is it possible to pass the input data through link, so that it automatically submits the form with the data present in the link.

Can the link be modified to something like:

https://www.amazon.in/gp/help/customer/ces/phone-popup.html?num=9846098460&time=now

Comment: Very possible. You just need a little javascript & php for that.

Comment: It is not possible for me to modify the page which is belonged to amazon.

Comment: Your get URL would be something like: `https://www.amazon.in/gp/help/customer/contact-us/jquery/initiate-trusted-contact.html/ref=?ie=UTF8&clientSessionId=278-4160447-6843713&ie=UTF8&c2cId=e78ca62e-2c7c-4d70-8bbc-e2e894cc2c77&callContextId=&callAfterMins=0&userCallbackNumber=%7B%22phoneNumber%22%3A%227777777777%22%2C%22country%22%3A%22IN%22%2C%22extensionDetails%22%3A%7B%22extension%22%3A%22%22%2C%22routeThroughReceptionist%22%3Afalse%7D%7D&virtualCall=false&screenShareRequested=0&token=&asin=&pollId=&pollResponseType=HN&_=1466231409670`

Comment: My bad @djsreeraj, tot that link was just an example and not the actual thing

Comment: Is the phone number int the link encoded?

Answer (score 0):

**Simple and drastic answer: NO.**

If **YOU** were the owner of the target site, you could foresee this kind of use...
Pretty rare uses for common people.

**If not:**
Are you trying some kind of an automatic query hack ??

Do you really think you will get such an answer on a public forum?
Think about it.

SO reviewers: **CLOSE THIS QUESTION!**

Comment: actually my need is not any hack, i dont regularly want to enter my phone number and get a callback instead get a callback just by clicking on the link. Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say so... The way the form data is sent to the remote server is probably through a HTTP POST request triggered from Javascript (when you click the "Call me" button). Therefore, it's not possible for you to automatically submit the form by passing the arguments in the URL.

Comment: Ohk I understood. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to show code so we better help you but here's a thought.

```
Yoursite?date=jaz&id=2323;
```

In your form, you do something like

```
<input type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['jaz']{echo $_GET['jaz']})) ?>"
```

Then in you Javascript
You can just submit the form when the page is loaded.

This is just a basic framework but you may want to consider security and check for emptiness when the actual form is submitted

Comment: Thanks. But the site does n't belong to me. And I dont regularly want to enter my phone number and get a callback instead get a callback just by clicking on the link. Thats it

Comment: It's next to impossible then chief